# Can I prevent users from logging in using Remote Desktop if a disconnected session exists?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

On Windows XP, if a user is connected to a XP client using Remote Desktop, a second user cannot log on -- regardless whether the RDP session is active or disconnected.

This has changed on PCs running Windows 7: If a user connects to a Windows 7 PC using RDP and disconnects the session later, a second user can log on using RDP while the first session is disconnected, resulting in two users being logged on simultaneously. Is there a way to configure the system in a way that it behaves like Windows XP, meaning that at any time only one user can be logged on?

I have disabled "Fast User Switching" and configured Remote Desktop via Group Policy to only allow one session ("Limit number of connections"), but that has not changed the behavior -- a second user can still log on using RDP if the first one has disconnected his / her session.

Comment: I think I have a step in the right direction: in Task Scheduler, you can have a task trigger -> On connection/disconnection of remote user. I don't understand your situation 100%, but I believe on disconnect you could log the user off or something.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My problem is not that a user disconnects the session -- that's OK, and automatic log off is not desired. The problem is that other users can log on while there is a disconnected session. Having more than one user logged on at any time is not acceptable to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the "official" answer from Microsoft given in the [Technet forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3992d98e-dc31-4c78-9f5c-51458a005c8a/can-i-prevent-users-from-logging-in-using-remote-desktop-if-a-disconnected-session-exists?forum=w7itpronetworking#3992d98e-dc31-4c78-9f5c-51458a005c8a):
*This is by design in Windows 7, when a session is disconnected, we can start a new session to connect to Windows 7, there is no need to log off from the host.*